# Template onload event for meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I know meteor exposes events such as "click", for DOM element but I'm wondering if there's a load event that's fired when a template or partial is loaded? How would I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For Meteor starting from 0.4.0 preview, you can use [`Template.myTemplate.created`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created).

In `Template.myTemplate.created` the DOM is not ready however.

If you need to manipulate the DOM, you might want to use [`Template.myTemplate.rendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) instead and use a boolean value to track the state within the Template object like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
    if(!this._rendered) {
      this._rendered = true;
      console.log('Template onLoad');
    }
}
```

Comment: `Template.myTemplate.rendered` is deprecated since Meteor 1.0.4. While it is still supported for backward compatibility, you may want to use `Template.myTemplate.onRendered` for newer versions. [Source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#blaze-2)

Answer (score 11):

Following should work.
Meteor.defer will get called once template is added to DOM and rendered.

```
<template name="temp">
    //regular stuff
    {{invokeAfterLoad}}
</template>

Template.temp.invokeAfterLoad = function () {
  Meteor.defer(function () {
     $('mydiv').jquerify();
  });
  return "";
};
```

Comment: As of v1.1.0.2 this pattern is deprecated. Use `Template.temp.helpers(...)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend this rather than the accepted answer, slightly less gross IMHO:

```
<template name="temp">
    {{aReactiveHelper}}
</template>

Template.temp.aReactiveHelper = function() {
  var someValue = Session.get('someValue');
  invokeAfterLoad();
  return someValue;
};

var invokeAfterLoad = function () {
  Meteor.defer(function () {
     $('mydiv').doSomething();
  });
};
```

The assumption is that you want to invoke something after the template loads because it's reacting to a reactive object.

The benefit here is you're not adding animation code to your template.

Comment: this is practically the same answer a Nachiket's