# Keep track of clients currently on a page

Tags: meteor, ddp

I would like to keep track of all clients currently on a page in my app. I am basically implementing something similar to live user list on Google Doc.

[image]

A naive approach would be to send a heartbeat to the server at an interval, when a client is on the page.

As an alternative, I am thinking about implementing the following:

1. Once a client connects, push the userId to an array in the db
2. Observe the DDP connection with the connection ID
3. Pull the userId when the DDP connection is closed

But I don't know if that is even feasible. Any ideas or a suggestion for a better solution?

**Edit**

I would like to only track status of  users on a certain page. Therefore [meteor-user-status](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) won't suit my needs.

Also I want to track anonymous clients (users who are not logged in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested data structure is perfectly reasonable. No need to overthink it!

One slight complication would be that you might have to manually manage your own `observeChanges` for the array in the db you are pushing userIds to. That's because meteor publications are not reactive on an `$in` query, which I assume you'd use to do something like `db.users.find({_id: {$in: arrayOfUsersOnPage}})`.

If you want to avoid that complexity (I know I do) then you could denormalize this information directly to the userDoc. When a user hits a route, you could push a unique ID of the page they're on to an array on their user doc like `connectedPages`. Then, your page would just need to subscribe to:

```
db.users.find({connectedPages: '_id_of_this_page})
```

which is natively reactive.

Obviously yes, you'd have to manually push/pull the page id to the user document. The easiest way to do that to my mind would be during the  and [`onDestroyed`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onDestroyed) Template events specific to each page.

Anonymous users gets a little trickier with this second implementation method, as they don't have user documents to denormalize to. If that's a requirement, I'd go with your first idea of a document for each page that contains an array of connected users.

---

To actually detect when a user loads a given webpage, I would suggest using the [`onCreated`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onCreated) hook in Blaze or (apparently) the `ComponentDidMount` in React. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167390/template-onload-event-for-meteor-js).

To detect page exit, I have found Meteor's publication `onStop` to be reliable. A good discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257958/server-cleanup-after-a-client-disconnects). Others would do this with a simple heartbeat, which I personally find to be very un-Meteor and cumbersome, but reliable.

Regarding how to uniquely identify each user, obviously those logged in will have `Meteor.userId()`. For those not logged in, you should rely on `Meteor.connection._lastSessionId` which is available only server-side. Update your page document server-side with this list of connected users and then make sure that page is published to all connected clients via the discusson above and you should have the data you need!

Comment: Thanks. Could you add more information? You said that my idea is feasible: could you edit the answer to explain how I might obtain the unique connection id and user information when a user connects to a specific page? I've looked at `Meteor.onconnection` but I can't call that only on a certain page.

Comment: Also, if I depend on `onCreated` and `onDestroyed`, I don't think I can account for a situation when the user quits the browser tab. I am using React, so the equivalent would be `ComponentDidMount` and `ComponentWillUnmount`, but the same question holds.

Comment: Sure thing, see above.

Comment: Your suggestion of using publication is ingenious. I can update the page document inside a publish function and use `onStop` to register a callback to pull user id from the document when a client disconnects. Thanks for this.